# Powershell pipeline access to ADComputer object "Info"

Tags: powershell

I've been trying to work with the following query to get AD info for my servers, but "Info" just comes back as blob of stuff. To me it looks like I should be able extract specific parts, but I've had little success. I've even tried to use regex to get what I need out, but I'm terrible with regex. Any help with how to extract the SN,MAC and IP from "Info" would be much appreciated.

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * -SearchBase $server | select -Property name,info
```

Comment: info flag is not populated by anything by default. If this attribute is populated where you work you probably have a logonscript that populates it or similar. If you need help with parsing the info-string you must specify how it looks.

Comment: Good to know about "Info" I guess I should've started there. Here is an example of the info-string: Sys=VMware, In|VMware Virtual Platf;SN=VMware-## ## ##;OS=Ver:6.3.9600,SP:0,Type:3,Architecture:64-bit;Form=Desktop;AGM=##.#.#/##.#.#;TPM=## TPM;MBE=#;FVE=;EFS=;NIC=M:############&I:###.###.###.###;MON=No Monitor;TimeInfoAdded=##/##/#### ##:##:## PM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using '-split':

```
$comp = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * -SearchBase $server 
$info = $comp.info

$SerialNumber = ($info -split 'SN=')[1] #replace with 'VMWare-' if desired
$SerialNumber = ($SerialNumber -split ';')[0]
```

This works with serial number assuming the output is formatted exactly as you have displayed it in the comments. It does, however, bring in that 'VMware' string included. Use the code in my comment if you would like just the #s.

You can copy that -split code out for the remaining fields you would like to extract.